# Cannot create sql server database in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, dreamspark

I have DreamSpark student subscription in Azure.
I'm following [Create an ASP.NET MVC app with auth and SQL DB and deploy to Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/) tutorial. 
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1 and Azure SDK 2.8.2.1.
But I'm getting error when I'm trying to add database to the project.

```
Template deployment failed. Deployment operation statuses:
Succeeded: /subscriptions/131474ef-becf-4444-98c3-aac7371dc3d2/resourceGroups/contactmanager/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/contactmanagerUmriyaevPlan ()

Succeeded: /subscriptions/131474ef-becf-4444-98c3-aac7371dc3d2/resourceGroups/contactmanager/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/contactmanagerumriyaevdbserver ()

Succeeded: /subscriptions/131474ef-becf-4444-98c3-aac7371dc3d2/resourceGroups/contactmanager/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/contactmanagerumriyaevdbserver/firewallrules/AllowAllAzureIPs ()

Failed: /subscriptions/131474ef-becf-4444-98c3-aac7371dc3d2/resourceGroups/contactmanager/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/contactmanagerumriyaevdbserver/databases/contactmanagerumriyaev_db ()
status (): 
error (ResourceDeploymentFailure): The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.
Succeeded: /subscriptions/131474ef-becf-4444-98c3-aac7371dc3d2/resourceGroups/contactmanager/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/contactmanagerumriyaev ()

Succeeded: /subscriptions/131474ef-becf-4444-98c3-aac7371dc3d2/resourceGroups/contactmanager/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/contactmanagerumriyaev/config/connectionstrings ()
```

It's successfully creating resource group, application, sql server. However, it's failing to create database in that sql server.

I also tried to add database to the created sql server using [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com), but it also failed.

However, I was able to create database for `Mobile App Services Quickstart` tutorial.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [DreamSpark Website](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=99) states that SQL Database is included in the program but there's no mention of the limitations.  My guess is that either:

- You're limited to one database
- You selected a database size not included in the program

Comment: I also thought like that and tried to delete my only database in the cloud. It helped me to create database using portal. Then I deleted it and tried to do the same using VS. But it again failed.